# Using post method on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Total noob to Rails. Trying to provide a link for my students to join a class (create a new `Attendance` model which will store a `class_session_id` and a `student_id`).

However, what I've tried gives me a flash error, which comes from this code in my class_sessions_controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :update 
before_action :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy] do
  if !current_student || !current_student.admin?
    flash[:alert] = "You must be logged in as an administrator to control class sessions"
    redirect_to :class_sessions
  end
end
before_action :set_class_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

However, I don't see how I'm calling new, create, edit, or destroy on the class session. By the way, I'm logged in as a non-admin so `current_student` is not nil and `current_student.admin?` is false.

Here's what I tried:

```
<%= link_to "Join", {class_session_id: class_session.id, student_id: current_student.id}, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to join this class?" } %>
```

I also have a test which passed for this same task I'm now trying to perform:

```
test "students can make attendances for themselves" do
  assert_difference('Attendance.count', 1) do
    sign_in students(:not_an_admin)
    post :create, attendance: { class_session_id: class_sessions(:one).id, student_id: students(:not_an_admin).id }
  end

  assert_redirected_to attendance_path(assigns(:attendance))
end
```

Here are my models for reference

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :class_session
end

class ClassSession < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attendances
    has_many :students, :through => :attendances
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :class_sessions, :through => :attendances
end
```

Here's what the console was saying at the time:

```
Started POST "/class_sessions?class_session_id=5&student_id=9" for ::1 at 2015-01-12 11:09:57 -0800
Started POST "/class_sessions?class_session_id=5&student_id=9" for ::1 at 2015-01-12 11:09:57 -0800
Processing by ClassSessionsController#create as HTML
Processing by ClassSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3VN01Qj1HV0iqoOdV5c/SwW/6ONhDdcIA59xA38/JR8K3xVfRF8/GwnQ80jwLnfXKu6xlRA91qhPK9ECJsxLTQ==", "class_session_id"=>"5", "student_id"=>"9"}
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3VN01Qj1HV0iqoOdV5c/SwW/6ONhDdcIA59xA38/JR8K3xVfRF8/GwnQ80jwLnfXKu6xlRA91qhPK9ECJsxLTQ==", "class_session_id"=>"5", "student_id"=>"9"}
  Student Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "students"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  Student Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "students"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/class_sessions
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/class_sessions
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f83e91cd7b0@/Users/michaelsnowden/mvgate/app/controllers/class_sessions_controller.rb:3> rendered or redirected
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f83e91cd7b0@/Users/michaelsnowden/mvgate/app/controllers/class_sessions_controller.rb:3> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

I can easily create a new attendance as an admin for any student and class session using the attendances/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@attendance) do |f| %>
  <% if @attendance.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@attendance.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this attendance from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @attendance.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :student_id, collection: Student.all, label_method: :email %>
  <%= f.input :class_session_id, collection: ClassSession.all, label_method: :short_description %>
<% end %>
```

And I've tested that this works in the console via

```
s = Student.first # Me, the admin
s.attendances.first # #<Attendance id: 3, class_session_id: 5, student_id: 8, ... >
s.class_sessions.first # <ClassSession id: 5, ...>
```

Is it just as simple as my syntax for the link_to post being wrong, or is it something more complicated involving my class_sessions_controller?

Comment: You have not passed route_path in link_to helper, I think this may be the problem. If you can post error log in question then its easier to debug problem

Comment: @AnilMaurya How do I add a route_path in the link_to helper. From the error log, I think you're right because `Started POST "/class_sessions?attendance%5Bclass_session_id%5D=5&attendance%5Bstudent_id%5D=9"` tells me that it's at the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

prepare your link like this : (i am assuming you have a join action in your controller)

```
<%= link_to "Join", 
   join_class_sessions_path(class_session_id: class_session.id,
   student_id: current_student.id),  method: :post, 
   data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to join this class?" } %>
```

how you construct your method:

```
actionname_controller_path(extra_attribute: value)
join_class_sessions_path(class_session_id: class_session.id)
```

#ClassSessionsController.rb

```
class_sessions_controller.rb    
 def join
   raise params.inspect 
   #here by raise you can see all your parameters and 
   #add your logic as per your need.
 end
end
```

Comment: I don't have a join action in my controller. Do I need one? I can still create attendances that are linked up to students and class_sessions via the attendances_new_path, but I'm only giving access to that for admins.

Comment: Well, if you have a route that works, but you aren't allowing students access to that route (attendances_new_path), then you will indeed need a new route accessible by students, and a controller method for that route to invoke - perhaps the 'join' suggested by Ajay.

Comment: "can still create attendances that are linked up to students and class_sessions via the attendances_new_path" - this one is for creating attendance.
For joining the students, similarly you may need to have a new action, (like join as I suggested) and write the join related functionality/code there !@doctordoder

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems:

- The error log showed me I was at the wrong route, so I added an attendances_path before my parameters
- My parameters were missing a key for the attendance itself

This fixed both of those, and now everything is working fine:

```
<%= link_to "Join", attendances_path({:attendance =>{ class_session_id: class_session.id, student_id: current_student.id}}), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to join this class?" } %>
```